# CSS dropdown not closing on click

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I hope you could help me to hint what I have done wrong, because my dropdown won't close when the user clicks on one of the subitems. It just stays open until you click anywhere outside.

I am still quite a novice when it comes to css and jquery, so please don't be too hard on me ;)

Here is a link to the development of the site:
http://prestigetrips.com/pricklybay/

When you hover over "Marina", that's the dropdown.

Here is my css:

```
 #mainnav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 700px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    float: right;
    right:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    z-index: 100;
}
#mainnav ul {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
#mainnav ul li a {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#mainnav ul > li:first-child a{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#mainnav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#mainnav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#mainnav ul ul {
    background: rgb(88,38,125); 
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 44px;
    left: 0px;
    width:250px;
}
#mainnav ul ul li {
    float: left; 
    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B6A0C1;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(234,222,239);
}
#mainnav ul ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
#mainnav ul ul li a {
    color: rgb(223,207,231);
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 22px 12px 22px 90px;
}
#mainnav ul ul li:first-child a{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#mainnav ul ul li:hover{
   margin-right: 0;
}
#mainnav ul ul.dropdown li:nth-child(2) hover + li {
    margin-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B6A0C1;
}
#mainnav ul ul li a:hover {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
     -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
     color: #fff;
}
#mainnav ul ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(123,73,146,0.9);
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border: none;
}
#mainnav ul li.active > a, #mainnav ul li.active {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

And my javascript for the slideUp / slideDown (I assume I have to add something here to make the menu close on click?):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mainnav li').hover(function(){
            $('ul', this).slideUp(0).stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
        },

        function(){
            $('.dropdown', this).css("display", "block").stop(true, true).delay(50).slideUp(300);
        });

    });
```

I hope you can help me out, thank you all in advance!

Comment: I suppose you could just add a new event handler for the mouse click

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no handler for the click of the dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainnav li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(0).stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
    }, function () {
        $('.dropdown', this).css("display", "block").stop(true, true).delay(50).slideUp(300);
    });

    //hide it on click
    $('#mainnav ul ul li').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown').css("display", "block").stop(true, true).delay(50).slideUp(300);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help! The click function works, but when you click on "Marina" and "Dockage & ....", it scrolls down to the respective anchor target, and then the dropdown "flickers" open and close again. How do I adjust the function to avoid the flickering?

Comment: @BelindaBaumgartner did you apply the changes in the test site you posted above?

Comment: Yes, I updated it now, can you please check again and let me know what there is still wrong with it? Thank you so much!

Comment: @BelindaBaumgartner The issue of flickering is not coming for me

Comment: Hm, when I click on it, it closes and then opens again. Did you click on the first sub item? I have tested on Chrome.

Comment: @BelindaBaumgartner yes... `Dockage & Technical Services` isn't it

Comment: Ok, I made a screencast, because it does open and close again sometimes, and I just can't figure out why? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCHy5WgZ238

Comment: Any help on this? Here is another link, and it also "flickers" open after clicking on an item: http://stage.pricklybaymarina.com/index.php?id=1